# Cannot access offset of type string on string when creating json in php

Tags: php, json

I have read a million times a million answers to this question and I just can't seem to get it working myself.

I have a file that starts out empty called contact.json.

If empty I need to add json data to it. If not empty I need to append json data to it.

For some reason, every method I have tried results in a file that php says is a text string, not valid json when reading it back.

My code to write is as follows.

```
if (isset($_POST)) { 
  $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
  $phone = strip_tags($_POST['phone']);
  $msg = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
  $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
  $file = '../json/contact.json';
  $array = array('name' => $name, 'phone' => $phone, 'email' => $email, 'msg' => $msg);

  if (file_exists($file)) { 
    $contact = file_get_contents($file);
    if ($contact != '') { 
      $tempArray = json_decode($contact,true);
      array_push($tempArray, $array);
      $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
      file_put_contents($file, $jsonData);
    } else {
      $json = json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
      file_put_contents($file, $json);
    }
  }
}
```

After 2 entries a json file ends up looking like this:

```
{   
  "name": "example name 1",
  "phone": "111111111",
  "email": "email@addr.com",
  "msg": "test message",
  "0": {
    "name": "example name 2",
    "phone": "111111111",
    "email": "email@addr.com",
    "msg": "test message 2"
  }
}
```

When I try to do a basic readback loop I use this code...

```
$file = '../json/contact.json';
$comments = file_get_contents($file);
$comments = json_decode($comments, true);

foreach ($comments AS $i => $comment) { 
  echo $comment[$i]['name'];
  echo $comment[$i]['email'].'<br>';
  echo $comment[$i]['phone'].'<br>';
  echo $comment[$i]['msg'].'<br>';
}
```

Above returns:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in read_comments.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in read_comments.php on line 7
```

and if I simply

```
echo file_get_contents($file);
```

it echos as text without error.

In the very near future (as soon as I solve this) I am also going to need to be able to delete arrays from the json object until there are no entries left.

So how do I do this correctly to end up with properly formatted json?

Comment: If the file is empty, you write *one* array into it. But you want it to be an *array of arrays* instead. And you have too many redundant code paths. The logic should be simple: if the file exists and isn't empty, read its contents into a variable. This variable should be an *array of arrays*. If the file doesn't exist or is empty, then initialise the variable yourself as an empty array. This is where the if..elses should end. From here you have an (empty) array of arrays. You can push your new data into this array, and then write it back to the file.

Comment: Thank you so much... something so simple... if empty make it an array.... :)

Answer (score 1):

In this part

```
foreach ($comments AS $i => $comment) { 
  echo $comment[$i]['name'];
  echo $comment[$i]['email'].'<br>';
  echo $comment[$i]['phone'].'<br>';
  echo $comment[$i]['msg'].'<br>';
}
```

you are trying to use your key in your value not the item itself.
Your main item (which holds the keys and value is 'comments' and you've used 'comment' which is the value itself).

So change it to

```
foreach ($comments AS $i => $comment) { 
  echo $comments[$i]['name']; // here (comment to comments)
  echo $comments[$i]['email'].'<br>'; // here
  echo $comments[$i]['phone'].'<br>'; // here
  echo $comments[$i]['msg'].'<br>'; // here
}
```

Comment: Or just `echo $comment['name']`…

Comment: I  believe both work but I specifically used $i to identify the arrays for easier (I think) deleting arrays and rebuilding and resaving in the future.